# Library for Robot Framework which uses Page Object Model and AppiumLibrary

Tags: library, software-testing

My goal is to write Page Object with Robot Framework.

I found this: [boakley-library](https://github.com/boakley/robotframework-pageobjectlibrary)

I want to test a mobile application so the base keywords should be from the [AppiumLibrary](https://serhatbolsu.github.io/robotframework-appiumlibrary/AppiumLibrary.html).

What options do I have?

Comment: I am interested in the exact same thing.